# NativeScript Execution failed for task: Error while merging dex archives

Tags: android, vue.js, gradle, build, nativescript

While building NS + Vue application, following error occurred -

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives
```

Error is because the number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Error also directs to the solution at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

This solution suggests to enable multidex for apps with over 64K methods i.e. to add `multiDexEnabled true` in `build.gradle` which resolves the error.

In NativeScript `build.gradle` is located in `platforms/`, so whenever I clean the platform with `tns platform clean` or remove `platforms/`, I have to again add `multiDexEnabled true` in `build.gradle`.

Is there any permanent solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `build.gradle` in `platforms/`, use `app.gradle` in `App_Resources/Android`.

Add `multiDexEnabled true` inside `android.defaultConfig` in `app.gradle` file, this will persist and will not change with `tns platform clean` or removing `platforms/`

Comment: can u explain little bit more? 

my app.gradle only has this

`android {  
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []
  }  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
} `

so where i need to paste `multiDexEnabled = true`?

Comment: In `android.defaultConfig`

Comment: thank u the build is now successful. Now app crashes "unfortunately, app has stopped". I tried everything from clearing platform to changing devices.

Comment: Can you please share contents of app.gradle?

Comment: Exact copy paste of app.gradle.

`android {  
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []
    multiDexEnabled true
  }  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
} `

Comment: Everything was fine until i reinstalled firebase plugin to enable authentication feature.

Answer (score 2):

edit `app\App_Resources\Android\app.gradle`

add line **multiDexEnabled true**

```
android {
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId = "com.your.app"
  }
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
}
```

then delete folder `platforms/` and 
re-run your apps!